# ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider Random Errors

Tags: .net, active-directory, connection

I have a web application that is using the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider class to create/update/authenticate users against a secure LDAP system. Everything appears to be running fine except that we get random "The server is unavailable." exceptions. When users receive this error they can immediately try again and it works.

I had our network guy monitor the traffic and we noticed that the Membership object creates 2 secure TCP connections to LDAP (we will call them con1 and con2). Both connections appear to remain open but only con2 receives any communications. Eventually con1 will send a close request from the ldap server. This request appears to happen at random intervals. When we see the error we usually see the con1 close request immediately before the error happens (Milliseconds before).

I have read through the MSDN documents and cannot figure out why it opens 2 connections and why it does not close them or send a notification message that it is still up and running. Does anyone know these answers?

The second question I have is what can I do to fix this issue? I know I can just re-request the validation but I wouldn't expect I would have to.  Below is example code.

Config

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://FullyQualifiedServerName:636/OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX" />
<add name="ADMembershipProvider"    
type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
 connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" 
 connectionUsername="CN=XXX,OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX" connectionPassword="XXXXXX" 
 connectionProtection="Secure" enableSearchMethods="true" enablePasswordReset="true" 
 requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="XXXX" 
 description="Default AD connection" requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
 clientSearchTimeout="30" serverSearchTimeout="30" attributeMapPasswordQuestion="xxx" 
 attributeMapPasswordAnswer="xxxx" attributeMapFailedPasswordAnswerCount="xxxx" 
 attributeMapFailedPasswordAnswerTime="xxxx" 
 attributeMapFailedPasswordAnswerLockoutTime="xxxx" attributeMapEmail="mail" 
 attributeMapUsername="userPrincipalName" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="7" 
 passwordAttemptWindow="1" passwordAnswerAttemptLockoutDuration="5" 
 minRequiredPasswordLength="8" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
 passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).{8,20}$" />
```

Code

```
return Membership.Providers["ADMembershipProvider"].ValidateUser(userName, userPassword);
```

Environment: Windows Server 2008, IIS 7.0, .NET 4.0
***Note*** We are currently serving up very low volume as we are in a small beta window.

Comment: Only a comment and a reach.  Are you sure your PDC and BCD are up?   Are you sure you PDC and BDC are in sync?   I have seen similar symptoms in Citrix when PCD and BDC where not in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is a bug in the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider class. We ended up switching to the Common.LdapAuth.LdapAuthProvider class to authenticate users.